# How to handle derivative of absolute value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I just want to check if this is the correct way to handle $\frac d{dx} |f(x)|$.

Should you say $|f(x)| = \operatorname{sgn}(f(x))f(x)$ (where $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is the sign function which equals $\pm 1$, depending on the sign of $x$) and then take the derivative of this, where $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is a constant?  I.e. $\frac d{dx} |f(x)| = \operatorname{sgn}(x) \frac {df}{dx}$?

What about integration?  Can I also do $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx = \operatorname{sgn}(f(x))\int_a^b f(x)dx$?

Comment: Just have a look at the graph of $g(x)=|x|$ to see that this is not everywhere differentiable.

Comment: Oh yeah.  So I'd have to figure out where all of the cusps are first.  But does it work everywhere where there's not a cusp?

Comment: @user221523 The derivative simply doesn't exist where $f(x) = 0$. Apart from that, the chain rule dictates
$$|f(x)|' = \mathrm{sgn}(f(x)) f'(x)$$

Comment: Please look up the definition of weak derivative.  The function might have a derivative in this sense.

Comment: OK @Euler....IS_ALIVE  I'm about to have to go to class, but I'll look that up later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative simply doesn't exist where $f(x) = 0, f'(x) \ne 0$. Apart from that, the chain rule dictates
$$|f(x)|' = \mathrm{sgn}(f(x)) f'(x)$$
Conversely you have
$$\int_0^x |t|\ \mathrm dt = \frac12\mathrm{sgn}(x)x^2$$
wich can be used for integration.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  That's what I thought.  I'll accept this when it lets me later if no one has given a different answer.

Comment: The derivative does exist sometimes when $f(x) = 0$.  For example, if $f(x) = x^3$ then $\left.\frac{d|f|}{dx}\right|_{x=0} = 0$. And the integral trick only works when $f(x)$ is always non-negative or always non-positive on the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: @MarkFischler Actually $f(x) = f'(x) = 0$ is okay, but I added that. $|x^3|' = 3\mathrm{sgn}(x)x^2$

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left| f(X) \right| = \text{sgn}(x) \frac{df}{dx}
$$
is true for all $x$ such that either  $f(x) \neq 0$, or if $f(x) = 0$, then $f'(x) = 0$ as well. But not for the reason you state:  It is not valid to blithely treat $\text{sgn}(x)$ is a constant.  If it were, then those exceptions would not be exceptions.

The integration statement is completely wrong, and in fact ill-posed, since $x$ on the left is a dummy variable of integration, while $x$ is used outside the integral on the right.

Comment: There's a severe error in the equation (not sure if typo or not).

Comment: I'm talking about the argument of $\mathrm{sgn}$. Please fix.